# Using revalidate : 1 in StaticProps (ISR) vs ServerSideProps (SSR) in Next JS

Tags: next.js

My data is stocks in news so everyday once the data changes in my page but in order to keep the page up to date when the data is updated, I used revalidate:1 in getStaticProps it's working fine now but is this comparatively better than using getServerSideProps?
Note: My data updates only once in a day (every day morning)

Comment: If the data is only updated once per day, could you not increase the `revalidate` value? Making better use of the cached pages generated through ISR.

Comment: Yeah that's a good suggestion I tried doing that but the issue is let's say the news is getting updated at 9 am and most of the users visit the page around that time but unfortunately only cached page is rendered that time...I didn't wanted that to happen is there any way to atleast update the cache via trigger the build at that particular time or something else? Thanks for replying :)

Answer (score 0):

We have to consider whether the data fetched per user is personalised in nature, if its personalised towards the user currently logged in, its better to use **getServerSideProps** as it fetches the data during each request and pre-renders it every time, which doesn't involve the usage of caching in any way.

In the case of ISR, it's better suited for rendering a page with content common to all users. Background regeneration ensures traffic is served uninterruptedly, always from static storage, and the newly built page is pushed only after it's done generating. Even when revalidating, the visitor first receives the cached version and only then the updated version. This caching strategy is commonly known as “stale-while-revalidate.”

Having a revalidate score of 1s is low , knowing that u get the update only once a day, it would be better to have it revalidate once every 60s or 120s.

Server-side rendering would be slow on the first render and might decrease the performance when compared to ISR.